# How to convert string to nullable int LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I saw a lot of questions like this but seems I cant find anything to relate one to another and find solution for mine. I am using MVC 4 application where I have a dropdownlist with some values inside.

I am using viewbag to populate it.

```
ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleName");
```

In the view my dropdown looks like this.

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectedRole", ViewBag.Roles as SelectList, String.Empty)
```

The string `selectedRole` is getting the `RoleId` value from the view.

After this I am doing some LINQ to the database with `selectedRole` which says that I cannot convert string to Int inside my LINQ which I really want so I can return better results.

```
     public ActionResult SearchResults(string selectedRole, string selectedCourse, string SearchParam)
        {
            var members = (from m in db.Members
                           select m);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedRole))
            {
                members = (from m in db.Members
                           where m.UserRole == Int32.Parse(selectedRole)
                           select m);


            }
        //some more if's here...
        return View(members.ToList());
}
```

So the question is how to convert this `selectedRole` to Integer. Are there any rules to follow when converting in LINQ?

PS: I tried also `Convert.ToInt32(selectedRole)` which returns same error.

Comment: Saying "I receive an error" isn't enough. There are hundred of possible errors. You should write the error in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the question is irrelevant...

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedRole))
{
    int selectedRole2 = Int32.Parse(selectedRole);

    members = (from m in db.Members
               where m.UserRole == selectedRole2
               select m);
```

You don't do it in linq, you do it outside.

In general, you aren't using only Linq, you are using Linq-to-Sql or Linq-to-Entities, because `Members` is a table. Sadly at least Linq-to-Entities doesn't have any cast method. You can obtain something similar by using a user defined function, but it is a little complex. Linq-to-Sql instead should support `Convert.ToInt32` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882655.aspx)

Comment: Very simple solution, feeling dumb right now. I got on the same query the same error using `Convert.ToInt32` so I doubt it supports any conversion at all.